# How do I filter for both a null and a specific value in the same field in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-filters

So here's a field I have in one of my models:

```
year = models.ForeignKey(Year, blank=True, null=True)
```

Now I want to get all the objects of that model whose `year` field is either `null` or `specific_year`.

This is what I tried:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(year__isnull=True, year=specific_year)
MyModel.objects.filter(year__isnull=True).filter(year=specific_year)
MyModel.objects.filter(year__in=[specific_year, None])
```

but they all give me an empty result.

I am pretty new to Django, so maybe there is something I'm missing here, but I couldn't find an answer in the docs. So how can I filter for all the objects whose `year` field is either `null` or `specific_year`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Q` objects for complex filtering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

```
from django.db.models import Q

MyModel.objects.filter(Q(year__isnull=True) | Q(year=specific_year))
```

By default, using `,` or nested filtering would yield an `AND` result, whereas you need an `OR` result, for which you can use  `Q`